# setTimeout não funciona com For no javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou começando no mundo de javascript e estou com um dúvida que mata minha lógica. Eu quero que um método repita uma quantidade de vezes a cada certo tempo, porém não funcionando ao usar a estrutura de repetição For, podem me ajuda a entender por favor?

```js
var repetirFunc = function(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Texto');
    }, 2000);
  }
}


repetirFunc();
```

No exemplo acima eu gostaria que o "texto" repetisse 11 vezes a cada 2 segundos, porém demora 2 segundos somente o primeiro loop, depois disso ele te lança na tela todas as repetições.

**Imagem 1:** Os primeiros 2 segundo fica assim
[image: Os primeiros 2 segundo fica assim]

**Imagem 2:** Depois dos primeiros 2 segundos, ele te lança as 11 repetições de uma só vez
[image: Depois dos primeiros 2 segundos, ele te lança as 11 repetições de uma só vez]

obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está fazendo justamente o que foi pedido para ser feito. Você registra uma função no `setTimeout` e informa que daqui 2000 milissegundos essa função deve ser disparada. Note que quando você chama o método `setTimeout` o código continua executando normalmente, ele não aguarda 2000 milissegundos para continuar. Esse na verdade é o motivo de existir o `setTimeout`, para deixar seu código assíncrono, para que nesse tempo ocioso o JavaScript possa trabalhar com outras coisas.

Você terá que usar outra solução para o seu problema, um deles pode ser o uso do `setInterval` com um controle de variável.

```
var repetirFunc = function(empresa){
  var limite = 11;
  var i = 0;

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (i++ > 11) return clearInterval(intervalId);

    console.log('Texto');
  }, 2000);
}


repetirFunc();
```

Se quiser manter o uso de `setTimeout`, você pode calcular os milissegundos em cada iteração.

```
var repetirFunc = function(empresa){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Texto');
    }, 2000 * i);
  }
}


repetirFunc();
```

Comment: Funcionou Gabriel, muito obrigado.

Comment: Se resolveu o problema (e não precisa de mais nada), pode marcar como a  resposta correta... e de nada. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o que você esteja buscando seja o `setInterval` e não o `setTimeout`.

- setInterval: Vai rodar 1 vez a cada 2 segundos;
- setTimeout: Vai esperar 2 segundos para rodar todo o código;

Tente o seguinte código:

```
var repetirFunc = function(empresa){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log('Texto');
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você se quer testou o código que você propôs, amigo?

Comment: Então Celsom, deu o mesmo resultado que o código que postei, pois conforme minha logica, a cada loop do for() deveria ser executado a função  que estou passando no setTimeout() e deveria demorar 2 segundos.